# how to add difreent images to a jquery dialog box ? after adding choose one of them to save in php form before submiting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a php form for car rental website with different options to choose for the customer. If the customer wants a small car with seating capacity of 4 then a dialog box should appear with list of cars available, so he can choose from that options. I tried to do it, but no luck.

How to add different images to a jquery dialog box? After adding one choice of them to save in php form before submitting it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            $("#imgpopup").dialog({

                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons :{
                    "Save": function() {
                            $('#car').val($(this).attr("img") );
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        },


                }



            });
            $("#selectBox").change(function(){

                if ($(this).val()=="4")
                {
                    $("#imgpopup").dialog('open');          }
            });



        });


        </script>

</head>

<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

<select id="selectBox">
<option value="0">select</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7+">7+</option>

</select>
<input type="image" id="car" name="car" >

<div id="imgpopup">
<img  id="image1" src="car1.png">
<img id="image2" src


</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need ajax call to get the list car image url from server based on selected type  and replace it in imgpopup div and trigger this one $("#imgpopup").dialog('open');

Comment: You will have to set image in blob and then have to make ajax call to your server with file.

Comment: @JYoThI@Mehuljoshi thanks for your suggestions ,but am new to ajax can you help me give some examples .